# Changing the leaflet map language?

Tags: dictionary, leaflet

Please is it possible to ** change the language of leaflet map ** tiles in a specific area? like changing it to Arabic language

Comment: Leaflet by itself has no map data. The tiles you're using are from which source?

Answer (score 3):

If you use this [plugin for Leaflet which gives Google Map tiles](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins), then that will be based on your Browser settings according to [Google's API Concepts page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Language).

You can get Open Street Map labels in various languages by adding the language identifer to the tile server link.  Like this: `http://{s}.www.toolserver.org/tiles/osm-labels-ar/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` You still need the background tiles as well.

Here's a working [jsFiddle for Arabic](http://jsfiddle.net/js545/).

The list of languages can be found at [toolserver.org](http://toolserver.org/~osm/locale/).

For other tile servers, I don't imagine there is much in other languages, but that would specific to each company that generates them.